# Color gradients to show direction in polylines

Tags: qgis, line, color, direction

I am referring to this very useful hack to change the color gradient of buffered polygons in order to show direction (with a gradient from red to green, for example)

[hack](http://anitagraser.com/2015/01/11/a-line-gradient-style-hack/)

The only problem is that data defined properties is no longer a button in QGIS.  I am running 2.12.  How do I get around this?

Here is an example of the lines that I want to fill with gradient color to show their direction:

Any other suggestions on how to show direction would be welcomed!

[image]

This is one of my attempts but actually the color gradients are random

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the **Data defined properties** button still exists but has been changed and split for each property. I'm using QGIS 2.12.3:

[image: Date defined properties buttons]